# Unit test on a 16-bit embedded target

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, cross-compiling, bare-metal

I am currently trying to evaluate the best way of unit testing some code written for a [16-bit based dsPIC device](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/dsPIC33EP512MU810). The compiler used for compiling the C code for the target is [Microchip's XC16](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tools-tools-and-software/mplab-xc-compilers).

I was not able to find any emulation tools, such as QEMU for ARM. I would really like to use a unit testing framework like GTest or Cpputest for this. My last resort is to run these unit test on the target, but the chance of using any framework there is legible (build and space concerns). Another idea that popped in my head is to use GCC on the host with m16 flag to generate 16-bit code, but that a workaround that does not guarantee the same results, since XC16 is a different compiler (even though based on GCC).

Is there a generic, proper way of approaching this problem? The goal is to be able to use a unit testing framework, on a host PC, for a target with a different architecture.

Comment: You are asking for recommendation, so your question will likely be closed. -- Anyway, what do you want to test? Your source, or the compiler? If you want to unit-test your code, use any framework you see fit, and compile it for the build system. Then, do some integration tests on the target, especially when it comes to performance and memory. And if you suspect your target compiler, write specific tests for it. This approach commonly leads to better architecture and good coverage.

Comment: Hi, its not that much of recomendation question. Its more of how to cross compile for dsPic on the host pc, which is x86. The main problem is that I cannot run XC16 compiled code on my PC  as there is no emulation software I know of. Doing the ubit tests with different compiler and architecture can yield different results

Comment: If you get different results, for example because of using `int`, enhance your architecture and define a data type or use in example `int16_t`. Use a thin HAL (hardware abstraction layer), design a well defined architecture. -- Even if you use an emulator or the real hardware to run unit tests, the target's system commonly does not provide the "infrastructure" necessary to use testing frameworks. This is especially true if you want to collect test coverage data. And even more if you want to automate testing, which you shall do. -- So, the "_generic, proper way_" for me is to test on the PC.

Comment: Hi, thanknyou forbthe follow up. I get your point and agree that testing on the host is the only proper way here (at least before integration tests). Going down to 16 bits like you mentioned is one thing, but there are still issues with memory fragmentation and competilly different assembler underneath.

Comment: Sure. -- The different machine code is "just" a matter of compiler correctness. That's why I asked what you want to test. We need to differentiate between testing the correctness of our source code, and the correctness of the compiler. -- However memory issues can be another beast. They depend heavily on the details what you are thinking about. For example, in the C++ project I'm working on currently, we have a custom allocator. We test it on the PC, though, because the layer is really thin, it can be done by a small "emulation" module. More tests on the real hardware are necessary, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user busybee. Unit testing is supposed to be a simple, cheap method for verifying that your code behaves correctly. Code behaviour should not be influenced by word length, CPU architecture or memory fragmentation. This means you should be able compile and run both the test and your code directly on your PC, not on the target or an emulator.

Granted, you'll have to write your embedded code in a reasonably portable way for it to behave similarly on 16-bit PIC and 32-bit x86 (or 64-bit x86, if you're feeling adventurous). This means paying extra attention to integer/pointer types and writing shim wrappers for all relevant peripherals (ideally the shim layers are so trivial that the compiler is able to optimize them out altogether on the microcontroller).

Code that must talk directly to a peripheral device without a shim layer (i.e. drivers) cannot be easily unit tested. Haven't figured out a good solution for this - so far I just test those parts manually and try not to touch them too much afterwards.

This is what I do with my microcontroller projects (granted, I'm on a 32-bit architecture). Can't really imagine spinning an emulator or flashing a real micro each time I want to run the unit tests.